# Add Drop Down List to Filter JQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 application. I am also using JQuery Datatables (http://datatables.net/) to display tabular data within one of the Razor Views.

The Datatable is populated by a Ajax request to a method within my Controller which then returns Json Data. Below is the code and this works nicely.

**Razor View**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Shift/GetShifts",
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]],
            "aoColumns": [
                      { "sName": "shiftDateID", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftTitle", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "description", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "description", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftStartDate", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftEndDate", "visible": true, "bSortable": false }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, i'd like to be able to filter the data by having a drop down list for the columns **shiftTitle** and **description** . This is where I am having problems. I tried to follow this link http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html on how to do it. So I amended my code like so to include the **initComplete** property.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Shift/GetShifts",
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]],
            "aoColumns": [
                      { "sName": "shiftDateID", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftTitle", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "description", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "description", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftStartDate", "visible": true, "bSortable": false },
                      { "sName": "shiftEndDate", "visible": true, "bSortable": false }

            ],
            "initComplete": function () {
                var api = this.api();

                api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (i) {
                    var column = api.column(i);
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for me. The Datatable is still displaying the info, but no drop down lists are being displayed.

Could anyone please help me with this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**
I've updated my legacy code to this (based on comment from ChrisV), but now no data is pulled back into my Datatable.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Shift/GetShifts",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
            { "data": "shiftDateID" },
            { "data": "shiftTitle" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "shiftStartDate" },
            { "data": "shiftEndDate" }
        ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you please post your HTML?

Comment: You appear to have a versioning problem here. The datatables API was completely overhauled as of 1.10. Your existing code is all in the legacy syntax, while the example you linked is in 1.10. I'm guessing either the initComplete property itself or something in the function is not liked by the version of datatables you're running.

Comment: @ChrisV I might be correct. I have therefore updated my existing code to what I thought is the correct up to date syntax, but now no data is pulled back. Can you look at my updated question and see what is wrong?

Comment: Can't see anything immediately wrong. You're running datatables 1.10.x, yeah? Any errors or anything in the console? Can you post the json you get back from hitting /Shift/GetShifts?